With LINQ-to-XML, how can I avoid getting back verbose namespaces on the descendants after calling .Descendants()?
When I have an XDocument and I know a namespace but not its prefix, and I want to get a certain descendant with prefixes and not namespaces (e.g. exactly as it was in the original XML string), how can I?
For example, suppose I have
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gdp="http://example.com/asdf">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gdp:GetLotNum/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

So perhaps I'd try:
XElement envelope = XElement.Parse(soapEnvelopeXml);
XNamespace envelopeNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
return envelope.Descendants(envelopeNamespace + "Body").FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();

But that gives me full namespaces, resulting in:
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <gdp:GetLotNum xmlns:gdp="http://example.com/asdf" />
</soapenv:Body>

Whereas I want a fragment of the exact XML I started with:
<soapenv:Body>
  <gdp:GetLotNum/>
</soapenv:Body>

Can I just strip off the namespace declarations (but not prefixes) somehow? Or is there a more elegant way to more strictly get a subset of the XML I started with?

The XML fragment you want is, strictly speaking, malformed, and LINQ to XML is designed to never output malformed XML.  Internally XNode.ToString() uses an XmlWriter to write itself out, and the writer returned by XmlWriter.Create will always add any necessary namespaces to ensure its output is well-formed.
As a workaround, you could write out your element using the deprecated writer XmlTextWriter with Namespaces = false:

Gets or sets a value indicating whether to do namespace support.

When set to false it will treat qualified names like gdp:GetLotNum as local names.  Then you could manually iterate through all the nodes of your selected element and write each to the specified writer.  To do that, first create the following extension method:
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    // Gets the outer XML of the current container not including parent namespace declarations.
    public static string GetOuterXmlFragment(this XContainer element, bool indent = true)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(element);
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
            return reader.ReadOuterXmlFragment(indent);
    }

    // Reads the outer XML of the current XML node not including parent namespace declarations.
    public static string ReadOuterXmlFragment(this XmlReader reader, bool indent = true)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
        // Set XmlTextWriter.Namespaces = false so that reader.Name (including any namespace prefix) will be treated as a local name.
        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter) { Namespaces = false, Formatting = indent ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None })
        {
            var startDepth = reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.None ? -1 : reader.Depth;
            do
                ShallowCopyReadNodeFragment(reader, writer);
            while (!reader.EOF && (reader.Depth > startDepth || (reader.Depth == startDepth && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)));
        }
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
    
    static void ShallowCopyReadNodeFragment(XmlReader reader, XmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Rewritten from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/combining-the-xmlreader-and-xmlwriter-classes-for-simple-streaming-transformations
        // By Mark Fussell https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {   
            case XmlNodeType.None:
                // The node type is None when Read() has not yet been called.
                reader.Read();
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                Debug.Assert(!writer.Namespaces);
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name); // This is only guaranteed to work for qualified when namespace support is disabled on XmlTextReader.
                while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    writer.WriteAttributeString(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                reader.MoveToElement();
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                reader.Read();
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                // WriteNode() will advance the reader for all node types.
                writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                reader.Read();
                break;

            default:
                throw new XmlException(string.Format("Unknown NodeType {0}", reader.NodeType));
        }
    }
}

And now if you do:
XNamespace envelopeNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
string newXml = envelope.Descendants(envelopeNamespace + "Body").FirstOrDefault()?.GetOuterXmlFragment();       

The result will be
<soapenv:Body>
  <gdp:GetLotNum />
</soapenv:Body>

(Honestly I'm not sure it's worth the effort just to get a malformed XML fragment.)
Demo fiddle here.
